# How to add vlookup formula using data on another sheet?

Tags: excel, vlookup

***Add lookup formula:***
[image]

I need to add information as shown on OUTCOME yellow, adding Department info to a table with 3000 rows. Data with info based on separate Sheet.
Please have a look on picture provided.
THANK YOU!

Comment: Are you asking how to use [VLOOKUP](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vlookup-function-0bbc8083-26fe-4963-8ab8-93a18ad188a1)?

Answer (score 1):

You can do it in variety of ways. Suppose you have data in `Sheet2` and result will be displayed in `Sheet1`. Try below formulas

```
=VLOOKUP(A2,Sheet2!$A$2:$B$5,2,FALSE)
=INDEX(Sheet2!$B$2:$B$5,MATCH(A2,Sheet2!$A$2:$A$5,0))
=XLOOKUP(A2,Sheet2!$A$2:$A$5,Sheet2!$B$2:$B$5)
```

[image]

Comment: Using a name for the range on the other sheet makes these shorter and, perhaps, easier to read. Good though.

Comment: That is good idea but for beginner first need to understand how formula works. Then they can use `Name Manager`.